passing an allocatable multi dimensional fortran array to a C function
I have the following main program in Fortran
program test
use iso_c_binding
implicit none

real(c_double), dimension(:,:), allocatable :: a

allocate(a(2,3))

call c_func(a)

print *,a

end program test

c_func is a function in C that takes in the multi dimensional array a and modifies it.
void c_func (double **arr) {
      modifies the array arr here
}

Is there a way to do this? I can do it for 1 dimensional allocatable array, but not for higher dimensions. And I don't want to flatten the array.

As Eric says, the C function expects an array of pointers. You would have to prepare an array of c_ptr pointers to every column of your Fortran array. Changing the C function may be easier. Or not.

can you give me a minimal example of how to do this?

Are you trying to write a Fortran program which calls the given C function, or a C function which works with the given Fortran program? Does the C function care about the Fortran's array being allocatable? Is it important to you that c_func has an implicit interface in the Fortran main program?

I would like a C function that works with the above main program, and c_func does have an interface with the fortran main program

You could pass the dimensions and a pointer to the first element to the C function, and declare the arr parameter in the C function as a variable length array. I don't know Fortran that well, but this forum thread for the Intel Fortran compiler might help: How to pass an allocated array to C?

In current Fortran, interoperabilty for passing allocatable arrays from Fortran to C goes via "C descriptors".  That is also an entry into C interoperability with non-contiguous arrays, and other, related Fortran features that don't have native C analogs.  Among the advantages is that a C descriptor carries the rank and dimensions, so you do not have to pass those separately.

@EricPostpischil double **arr declares a pointer to a pointer to double, not an array of pointers.

@isrnick: Thanks, converted to an answer and fixed.

In C, double **arr does not declare a multidimensional array. It declares, at best, a pointer to an array of pointers to double. (Technically, it declares a pointer to one pointer to double, and it is common to put multiple pointers one after the other, making an array of pointers, so arr would be a pointer to the first element of an array of pointers to double.)
Due to C semantics, such a pointer can be used in source code with two subscripts like a multidimensional array, as in arr[i][j], but the layout in memory is very different. arr points to memory where there are pointers, not memory where there are many double values laid out in rows and columns.
To declare a pointer to (the start of) a multidimensional array, use double (*arr)[N], where N is the number of columns (in the C view) of the array. You may need to pass N to the function in an earlier parameter, unless it is a fixed value. The function declaration could be void c_func(size_t N, double (*arr)[N]). You might need to change size_t there to match the type the Fortran code is passing.

To complete the answer of @EricPostpischil, on the Fortran side the code should ideally define an explicit interface for the C function. And for if you really want to work on the array in the C function you should pass the 2 dimensions:
void c_func(int N, int M, double (*arr)[N])

interface
   subroutine c_func(n,m,arr) bind(C,name="c_func")
      integer(c_int), value :: n,m
      real(c_double) :: a(n,m)   ! a(n,*) or a(*) would also do
   end subroutine c_func
end interface

...

real(c_double), dimension(:,:), allocatable :: a
integer :: n, m
...
allocate( a(n,m) )
...
call c_func( n, m, a )
...


It may be worth noting, given the title of the question, that as the allocation occurs on the Fortran side that the allocatable attribute is irrelevant here.

@IanBush Sure, but I have just kept it, as it was in the code of the question.
